# list indexing in python code error

Tags: python, if-statement, indexing, runtime-error

I'm having a problem in my code with list indexing and I'm already aware of the fact that the indexing starts at 0.

The below code is supposed to take a word the user enters and then the user enters another sequence of letters and checks if all the letters from the first entry are in the second entry and if not then which letters are missing.

Here's my code. I have also pointed out the line of trouble and the error message which only occurs when the expression list has more values than the word list.

```
word = list(set(list(input('Enter the word you want to build:').lower())))
expression = list(set(list(input("Enter the letters it must build the word with:").lower())))
word.sort()
expression.sort()
count = 0
length_expr = len(expression)
length_word = len(word)
global letters_missing
letters_missing = word
print(length_word)
if word == expression:
    print("All letters present")
else:
    while length_expr > count:

        a = expression[count]
        count2 = 0
        while length_word > count2:
            if word[count2] == a:  # <---------------------------  **problem line**
                letters_missing.pop(letters_missing.index(a))
                break
            else:
                count2 += 1
        count += 1

    # Still in else statement

    if word == []:
        print('All letters required are present.')
    else:
        print("All letters aren't present. The following letters are missing:", letters_missing)
```

***Error message***
**
my input

```
Enter the word you want to build:hjk
Enter the letters it must build the word with:hjkl
3
```

the message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lawra/PycharmProjects/first/first.py", line 19, in <module>
    if word[count2] == a:
IndexError: list index out of range
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearer solution in my opinion

instead of

```
letters_missing = word
```

do

```
letters_missing = list(word)
```

That way, you make a copy of `word`. And `word` itself will not shrink.

Then at the end, instead of checking

```
    if word == []:
```

check

```
    if letters_missing == []:
```

Which makes the intent clearer. If there are no letters missing, then all your letters are present. (Otherwise it's like you're checking whether your word is gone?... Not clear to the reader.)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that **count2** continues to get bigger until the letter is detected in **word**.  If the letter isn't featured in **word** (like 'l' in your example), **count2** grows larger than the length of **word** which causes an error.  You'll need to create a condition that breaks the loop if count2 => len(word)

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your example was `word` kept getting smaller and eventually had no letters left. And when there are no letters left you were checking the index 0 of `word` thus throwing the error. Try adding

```
if count2 >= len(word):
    break
```

inside the second while loop.